# Нестандартная передача переменных методом POST

Tags: html, php

Доброго всем времени суток.
Есть страница `a.php`, а на ней форма, которая с действием (action) методом POST посылает данные странице `b.php` для обработки. Далее идет условие:

```
if (условия == удовлетворяют) {
    // выполняем действия 1 с переменными $iv1, $iv2, $iv3, $iv4
    // выполняем действия 2
    header("Location: c.php");
    exit;
}
```

Что нужно написать вместо "выполняем действия 2", чтобы данные методом post передавала бы переменные странице c.php?

Comment: А почему бы вам не использовать GET-запрос? В этом случае он больше подходит.

Comment: переменные я привел примерные, по настоящему их оч. много, и они оч. длинные, не каждый браузер такое прожует. основная причина - это для одной из страниц, отвечающих за безопастность

Comment: .

    это для одной из страниц, отвечающих за безопасность
Может быть Вам поможет [include][1]? Передавать странице на этом же сервере данные POST-ом это как-то мягко говоря нестандартно.
[1]:http://php.net/manual/ru/function.include.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем нужна страница `b.php`? В смысле зачем условия проверять на ней? Проверили условия на `a.php` и, в зависимости от результата, перешли на `b.php` или `c.php`.

Если на странице `b.php` ожидаются какие-то действия от юзера и в зависимости от них идет переход, то используйте скрытые поля для проброса данных.

На [забугорном ресурсе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653090/how-do-you-post-to-a-page-using-the-php-header-function) пишут, что для этого можно использовать curl или fsockopen(). Но если в этом возникла необходимость, то значит алгоритм взаимодействия у вас построен неправильно.

UPDATE. Используем `include`

```
if (условия == удовлетворяют) {
    // выполняем действия 1 с переменными $iv1, $iv2, $iv3, $iv4
    include "c.php";
    //В файле c.php работаем с переменными $iv1, $iv2, $iv3, $iv4
}
```

Comment: почитал про fsockopen(), сейчас попробую

Comment: вы можете обьяснить зачем нужна страница b.php? Откуда берутся условия из if ?

Comment: b.php - обрабатывает введенные данные, и лишь в 1/1000 случаев, когда нужна дополнительная обработка, ОЧЕНЬ сложная, нужно перекинуть несколько переменных на с.php (которую править нежелательно) вот и задачка, передать переменные странице с.php методом post. вообще, если бы вариант shurik'а сработал, я бы был счастлив

Comment: Добавил пример с include

Comment: сработало. гениально, жаль что не заметил сразу ответ ReinRaus )

Comment: @mixalef, я конечно извиняюсь, но вам в проктологи идти нужно! Какой талант! Какие идеи!!

Answer (score 3):

```
if (условия == удовлетворяют) {
    // выполняем действия 1 с переменными $iv1, $iv2, $iv3, $iv4
    // выполняем действия 2

    $ch = curl_init('http://yousite.com/c.php');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('iv1' => $iv1, ....));
    curl_exec($ch);
    exit;
}
```

по другому никак, но это бред.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() на строчке $ch = curl_init('http://yousite.com/c.php'); само собой я переправил сайт на нужных, и пробовал отдельно эту строку, без других

Comment: Значит никак. У нас не установлена библиотека cURL на вашем хостинге

Answer (score 1):

а зачем такие сложности? просто подключите файл  c.php - и отработайте его с параметрами

Comment: можно пример?